# How to detect if the files are succesfully download in tcpdf?

Tags: tcpdf

In my code given below ,

```
$pdf->Output($node->nid . '.pdf', 'D');
```

How can I detect whether files are downloaded ?
As while reading aout the Output function it does not mention anything regarding the return value.
So I guess it does not return any value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This **cannot** be detected as it occurs on the *client-side*. The end-user may click "Save" or "Cancel".

However by setting the `D` flag to `I` , like

```
$pdf->Output($node->nid . '.pdf', 'I');
```

You can make sure that you have succesfully rendered the PDF to the end-user. The end-user may scroll down and click the `Save` button to save the PDF. Saving it or not solely depends on the end-user .. again you won't be able to track this.

Comment: I just wanted to create a node as soon as file is download. How can I go about doing that ? Is hook_file_download() function of drupal invoked when tcpdf output function is called ?